# Remove extra comma and double-quotes in CSV file and extract specific columns

Tags: linux, ubuntu, csv, awk

I have a .csv file as below, what I need is to remove extra commas between double quotes and extract the 2nd, 3rd and 7th fields.

Example input:

```
John,qa,mv,tom,"principal, qa",6501234567,john@gmail.com
```

Output should look like this:

```
qa,mv,john@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use a proper CSV parser. For example, with ruby:

```
echo 'John,qa,mv,tom,"principal, qa",6501234567,john@gmail.com' | 
ruby -rcsv -ne '
  row = CSV.parse_line($_)
  puts CSV.generate_line([row[1],row[2],row[6]])
'
```

```
qa,mv,john@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Awk / sed solution

```
awk '{print  $2, $3, $7}' file |sed 's/"//g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use `perl's` built in module [Test::Parsewords](http://perldoc.perl.org/Text/ParseWords.html).

```
$ cat file
John,qa,mv,tom,"principal, qa",6501234567,john@gmail.com
```

```
$ perl -MText::ParseWords -lne '
   @line = parse_line(",", 1, $_); 
   print join "," , @line[1,2,6]
' file
qa,mv,john@gmail.com
```

Note that arrays are indexed at 0 hence use the index appropriately to print desired values.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is exactly two occurrences of `"`

```
awk -F',' -v OFS=',' '{sub(/".*"/,""); print $2,$3,$7;}' input.txt
```

Output:

```
qa,mv,john@gmail.com
```